# I can't retrieve data from Mysql database to Android application

Tags: android, mysql, database, json

i'm having a problem with my application trying to retrieve data from mysql database. when i run the application i get a message that I've created in the php code saying  "student not found".
Here is the java code:

```
    public class StudentEditAccount extends Activity {
    EditText txtsid;
    EditText txtfirstname;
    EditText txtlastname;
    EditText txtcoursecode;
    EditText txtphonenumber;
    EditText txtemail;

    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String sid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single student url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/example/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update student
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/example/update_product.php";

    // url to delete student
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/example/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_STUDENTS = "students";
    private static final String TAG_SID = "sid";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    private static final String TAG_COURSECODE = "coursecode";
    private static final String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studenteditaccount);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // getting student details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting student id (id) from intent
        sid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_SID);

        // Getting complete student details in background thread
        new GetStudentAccountDetails().execute();


        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting background task to update student
                    new SaveStudentAccountDetails().execute();

            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // deleting student in background thread
                    new DeleteStudentAccount().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete student details
     * */
    class GetStudentAccountDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StudentEditAccount.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading account details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting student details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", sid));

                        // getting student details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that student details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single student Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received student details
                            JSONArray studentsObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENTS); // JSON Array

                            // get first student object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject students = studentsObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // student with this sid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtfirstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputfname);
                            txtlastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputlname);
                            txtcoursecode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputcoursecode);
                            txtphonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputphonenumber);
                            txtemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputemail);



                            // display student data in EditText
                            txtfirstname.setText(students.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));
                            txtlastname.setText(students.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                            txtcoursecode.setText(students.getString(TAG_COURSECODE));
                            txtphonenumber.setText(students.getString(TAG_PHONENUMBER));
                            txtemail.setText(students.getString(TAG_EMAIL));


                        }else{
                            // student with sid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save student Details
     * */
    class SaveStudentAccountDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StudentEditAccount.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving account ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving student
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String sid = txtsid.getText().toString();
            String firstname = txtfirstname.getText().toString();
            String lastname = txtlastname.getText().toString();
            String coursecode = txtcoursecode.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = txtphonenumber.getText().toString();
            String email = txtemail.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_SID, sid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FIRSTNAME, firstname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LASTNAME, lastname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_COURSECODE, coursecode));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PHONENUMBER, phonenumber));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_EMAIL, email));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update student url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about student update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update student
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once student updated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteStudentAccount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StudentEditAccount.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Account...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting student
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", sid));

                // getting student details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete student", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // student successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about student deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once student deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
<?php

 // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["sid"])) {
    $sid = $_GET['sid'];

    // get a students from student table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM student WHERE sid = $sid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $students = array();
            $students["sid"] = $result["sid"];
            $students["firstname"] = $result["firstname"];
            $students["lastname"] = $result["lastname"];
            $students["coursecode"] = $result["coursecode"];
            $students["phonenumber"] = $result["phonenumber"];
            $students["email"] = $result["email"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["students"] = array();

            array_push($response["students"], $students);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no student found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No student found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no student found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No student found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

my question is: what is the problem that cause the application to display the message "Student not found" every time when i try to retrieve the data from Mysql database?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing space in your SQL query. It should be `SELECT * FROM student WHERE sid = $sid`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i put the space in that SQL query and i'm still getting that message: Student not found.

Comment: check if your query is definitely fine. ideally you output the exact query from php and then execute it against your db with a db client. two possibilities: 1. your sid is incorrect, or 2. there is not entry with this sid.